# watir-webdriver finding the index of a value within an array

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to locate the index of a certain table header based on the `:text` value held within that table header. I've collected all the table headers using `.ths` however I'm unsure what is the best way to do a search on this array to find the table header with the correct value inside. I tried using the array.index function however did not seem to work. I'm trying to avoid looping through the whole array to find the index if possible. 
Here is my snip-it of code.

```
location = @browser.table(:id, "sprintCalTable").tr.ths
index = location.index(data)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I got lost. What are you trying to do? Also, please post relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would collect all the text from the headers and then do the index.

```
headers = @browser.table(:id, "sprintCalTable").tr.ths.collect{ |x| x.text }
index = headers.index(data)
```

Not sure if you consider that too much like looping through the whole array.

Comment: ah that looks perfect Justin plus makes more sense. Thanks!